# Android native style

Tags: android, android-styles

I would to create a custom style that extends from buttonBarButtonStyle. However, I figured, by searching on the internet, that it's not possible to extends from a native style.

Where can I find the style source code ? Or how can I use it to create a custom style, that I'll use for my buttons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend existing styles. You have to take a look at your styles.xml file. In your base theme you can add this item:

```
<item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonBarStyle</item>
```

The you have to define the new style like:

```
<style name="MyButtonBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar">
    <!-- here go your custom attributes -->
</style>
```

You can also choose another parent like Holo or something else.